# How to know/test when an animation has finished playing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, animation

I am starting an animation via a button press. Here is the code for the button:

```
-(IBAction)startAnimation:(id)sender{
stick.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo 1.JPG"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo 2.JPG"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo 3.JPG"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo 4.JPG"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo 5.JPG"],nil];
[stick setAnimationRepeatCount:200];
stick.animationDuration = 0.5;
[stick startAnimating];
}
```

and when the animation is done, i want to have a button appear, to play another animation on the screen. How can i test or see when my animation is done playing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't told us what `stick` is, but it looks like a `UIImageView`. You can only call `isAnimating` to check whether the animation is still running but you don't get any notification and there's no delegate either. You can calculate the stop time (200 * 0.5) and thus set up a timer (add a little safety margin). This won't be 100% correct but it might be "good enough".

Comment: there is no easier way to do this?? I just want to add a button when the animation is finished playing! THnaks for the help!!

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an easier way. Have a look at the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), there's no delegate and no notification.

Comment: okay, so i should throw in an NSTimer and when it hits a certain time, enable a button(or set its "hidden" property to "no")? Thanks again for the help!!

Answer (score -1):

If you called your animation using blocks, you could use a completion block.

[Here is a tutorial you can refer to](http://objcolumnist.com/2010/09/19/core-animation-using-blocks/) which shows a couple different ways to call animation routines on iOS.  This tutorial also shows what you can do for completion if you don't feel like using blocks (namely UIView's [`setAnimationDidStopSelector`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationDidStopSelector%3a) method).